# How to modify the listview content in this situation in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on a alarm application. The structure is somehow complex. It works like that:

The main activity is a FragmentTabhost activity, it has 4 tabs, one of the fragment is the alarm list.

So, the alarm is trigger by alarmManager, it first call the boardcast receiver , in the receiver there is a service , that start a new activity, showing the detail info. of the alarm.

And that is it. What I would like to do is when the user onbackpress that new activity, I would like to update the alarm list in that fragment. How to achieve that? Thanks for helping

Update : Attempt use Boardcast receiver but it does not receive

**in the Alarm Activity**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d("test1","test R1");
        Intent intent = new Intent("on_alarm_remove");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ctx).sendBroadcast(intent);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

**in the Alarm tab Fragment**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ctx = getActivity();

        intentFilter = new IntentFilter("on_alarm_remove");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ctx).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, intentFilter);
}

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("test1","test R");
            db.removeRecord(db.getFirstAlarm().alarm_id);
            reloadFragment();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mMessageReceiver != null)
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ctx).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }
```

**In manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".reminder.ReminderFrag$mMessageReceiver" />
```

It doesn't crash, but nothing happen, In the log "test R1" has run but "test R" does not. Thanks again for helping

Comment: So, what have you tried so far ? Post some code so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this only needed if the fragment is present, then you can get the fragment by id in the activity:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
  Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById( ... ); // Fragment's Id 
  if (f.getClass() == AlarmFragment.class) {
     ((AlarmFragment)f).removeRecord();
     return;
  }
  super.onBackPressed();
}
```